# variable with mongodb dotnotation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I want to increase a field inside an object object inside a mongodb document by 1.

```
  var stuffID = 5
  collection.update({
    "id": id,
  },
  {
    '$inc': {
      'stuff.stuffID': 1
    }
  },
  function(err, doc) {
    res.end('done');
  });
```

I need to make that stuffID a variable. Any way to do that? Thanks.

This is using node-mongodb-native if that helps.

If you're voting to close can you explain what it is you don't understand?

Comment: In what sense do you want to "make that stuffID a variable"?

Comment: @cwb like if stuffID is actually a different value and not the string stuffID.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create your variably-keyed object separately, because JS before ES2015 doesn't permit anything other than constant strings in object literal syntax:

```
var stuffID = 5
var stuff = {};                 // create an empty object
stuff['stuff.' + stuffID] = 1;  // and then populate the variable key

collection.update({
    "id": id,
}, {
    "$inc": stuff               // pass the object from above here
}, ...);
```

**EDIT** in ES2015, it's now possible to use an expression as a key in an object literal, using `[expr]: value` syntax, and in this case also using ES2015 backtick string interpolation:

```
var stuffID = 5;
collection.update({
    "id": id,
}, {
    "$inc": {
        [`stuff.${stuffID}`]: 1
    }
}, ...);
```

The code above works in Node.js v4+

Answer (score -3):

Put the variable where it says stuffID.

```
'stuff.' + varname: 1
```

Comment: `      'stuff.' + stuffID: 1

      
         ^



module.js:301

    throw err;
    
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
`

Comment: I don't think you can put a + in a key?

Comment: Then put the 'stuff.' in the variable too and you won't have to concatenate.

Comment: Well therein lies the rub, the variable is going to be interpreted as the field name and you're going to end up with varname : 1 in your document.