# Mongodb - Query embedded object with variable key

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo DB with the following object:

```
"clients" : {
    "x" : {
        "clientId" : "x1",
        "mainInfo" : {
                       ...
        },
        "events" : 
            {
            "58a176bbc3588410cd5450c6" : {
                "clientType" : "5001",
                "location" : "60001"
                }
            "58a176bbc3588410cd5450c8" : {
                "clientType" : "5001",
                "location" : "60002"
                }
                  ....}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to query where 'clients.x.events.(variable id).clientType' = 50001. Is there a way to drill down inside the events embedded object to get all records matching  "clientType" : "5001"?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. Consider converting the `events` field to an array, querying would thus be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the key value pair object like below.

```
var variable_id = <your variable id>;
db.collection.find({ [ 'clients.x.events.'+variable_id+'.clientType' ]:5001 });
```

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702450/variable-with-mongodb-dotnotation)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.It works for me.

> Use the $where operator to pass either a string containing a
>   JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query
>   system.

```
db.collection.find({"$where" : function(){ 
    for( var c in this ){
        if( c == "x" ){ 
            for(var i in this[c]){ 
                 for(var j in this[c][i]){
                      if(j == 'clientType' && this[c][i][j] == '5001'){
                           return true;
                      }
                 }
             }
        };
     }
     return false; 
}});
```

Hope this helps.